# Writing an ItemArray that contains NULLS

Tags: sql, vb.net, streamwriter

I'm trying to write a datarow out to a text file with delimiters between each value and this works fine until the SQL Table has any NULLs in it.

I can possibly just remove the NULL values from the table and block any new rows being able to have NULL and just have empty strings instead but wondered if there was a neater way to replace the NULL without having to loop through each column.

Currently I just use a JOIN (in VB.NET) to link all the values with my delimiter to create a string and then write out to a text file. I tried adding .ToString or using a Replace but neither managed to stop an exception

```
        Using objTextFile As New StreamWriter(Path.Combine(strTextFilePath, strTextFileName), False) 
            For Each setting As DataRow In recipeDataSet.Tables(0).Rows
               objTextFile.WriteLine(Join(setting.ItemArray, "|"))
            Next
            objTextFile.Flush()
            objTextFile.Close()
            objTextFile.Dispose()
        End Using
```

Comment: I see no SQL above. Are you expecting a SQL answer?

Comment: why not replace all NULL with ' '

Comment: As said above I'm trying to just remove the NULL at the point I write out the string without changing the underlying SQL data or iterating through each value as I go. Currently the code will just write each value from the DataRow out with a pipe in between  e.g. NWBG|NWBG-CG07|Y|Y|N|0|0| but any NULL values returned will cause an exception. I know I can amend the SQL query/SP and deal with ISNULL up there but thought there might be a neater way to just deal with it when it joins each element in the ListArray

Comment: open a second table with the replaced NULL's and go with it. no need for that case to hustle with more complex procedures. Or you run over all columns and make a stirn g concatination

Comment: As @nbk suggested, I think it would be the easiest way to modify your SELECT statement using the (SQL) [`ISNULL()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/isnull-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) function.

Comment: Yeh, I'm starting to think there is no easy way to just replace as it does the join which is a shame, I can amend the SP to just do ISNULL to every column in the SELECT query but that seemed a bit longwinded, I'd hoped I could just add .ToString at the end of the join command.